# How to force MySQL out of TRADITIONAL mode?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have an old application that started failing after an upgrade from MySQL 5.0 to 5.1.

A bit of research indicated this is due to "strict mode" which prevents inserting certain types of "invalid" values which previously were just automatically converted to something reasonable.

I tried `SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = ''` and `SET @@GLOBAL.sql_mode = ''` but I still get the error.

Also tried commenting out `sql_mode` in the `my.ini`.

Is there a stronger, sort of "nuclear" option to fix this?

Comment: Those *reasonable* replacements include dates as '0000-00-00', foreign keys as `0`, empty strings in ENUM fields... In my experience, that tends to complicate everything since stuff like `WHERE start_date IS NULL` doesn't work as expected and you must resort to `WHERE start_date IS NULL OR start_date='0000-00-00'`. You should patch your production environment with the appropriate SQL Mode but also enforce strict modes in your development box and try to fix the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my application I usually make sure that the MySQL connection is using traditional mode by issuing

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES,TRADITIONAL'
```

on each new connection. I presume that if you just issue

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = ''
```

on each new connection, you will have solved the problem.

You should be able to change the default SQL mode for new connections by issuing

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = ''
```

but you must use an account with sufficient privileges to do this or it won't work.

I think that if you want to make sure a particular SQL mode is in operation for your application, the most robust way to do so is to set it for each and every new connection.

Comment: Thanks... Apparently my problem was the syntax. SET SESSION sql_mode works but SET @@SESSION.sql_mode didn't. Also looks like I have to put this into every stored procedure.

Comment: You do not have to put it into every stored procedure. When a stored procedure is executed, the SQL mode is temporarily changed to the SQL mode that was in effect when the procedure was defined. You could just redefine every stored procedure with your chosen SQL mode in effect, as a one-time thing. Alternatively if you have an account with sufficient privileges, you could run an UPDATE query on the relevant INFORMATION_SCHEMA table to change the SQL mode settings for your procedures.

Answer (score 0):

To allow invalid dates, you need:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

But you'd better fix your application.